# Spring MongoTemplate insert succes or failed

Tags: spring, mongodb

How do I check if the value that is inserted into the collection using a `MongoTemplate` is saved successfully?

```
MongoTemplate template;
User user=new User();
user.name="Mark";
user.email="mark@mark.com"
template.insert(user);
```

Insert , save or any method in MongoTemplate does not return true or false.

Answer (score 1):

It will throw an exception here is the flow of methods:

```
template.insert(object) 
|
|
templateinsert(Object objectToSave, String collectionName)  
|
|
protected <T> void doInsert(String collectionName, T objectToSave, MongoWriter<T> writer)
|
|
protected Object insertDBObject(final String collectionName, final DBObject dbDoc, final Class<?> entityClass)
|
|
```

Here is the source code for insertDBObject

```
    protected Object insertDBObject(final String collectionName, final DBObject dbDoc, final Class<?> entityClass) {
    if(LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug("Inserting DBObject containing fields: {} in collection: {}", dbDoc.keySet(), collectionName);
    }

    return this.execute(collectionName, new CollectionCallback() {
        public Object doInCollection(DBCollection collection) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
            MongoAction mongoAction = new MongoAction(MongoTemplate.this.writeConcern, MongoActionOperation.INSERT, collectionName, entityClass, dbDoc, (DBObject)null);
            WriteConcern writeConcernToUse = MongoTemplate.this.prepareWriteConcern(mongoAction);
            WriteResult writeResult = writeConcernToUse == null?collection.insert(new DBObject[]{dbDoc}):collection.insert(dbDoc, writeConcernToUse);
            MongoTemplate.this.handleAnyWriteResultErrors(writeResult, dbDoc, MongoActionOperation.INSERT);
            return dbDoc.get("_id");
        }
    });
}
```

which will throw exception when you write fails, They are runtime exception. Runtime excpetions are translated by MongoExceptionTranslator
.So any insert which doesn't throw any exception is successful.

Comment: But document does not say it throws exception or anything like that.

Comment: Here is the ink for grepcode http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.7.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java

Comment: Some circumstances would let mongo not write the data are 
1.Disk space full, 2. Sever down 3. Access rights
We can easily reproduce 1 and 3. Run the code put the debugger before insert happens. Code execution stops. Shutdown the monogo server or revoke the write rights from the user and then resume. It should throw exception.

Comment: @andyPaul, RuntimeExceptions should be documented only in rare cases.